# Given $X\sim\text{Binomial}(m,p)$ and $Y\sim\text{Binomial}(n,p)$, calculate $\textbf{P}(X = x | X + Y = s)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, variance, expected-value

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent RV's such that $X\sim\text{Binomial}(m,p)$ and $Y\sim\text{Binomial}(n,p)$. Determine

(a) $\textbf{P}(X = x \mid X+Y = s)$

(b) $\textbf{E}(X\mid X + Y)$ and $\textbf{V}(X \mid X+Y)$

(c) Check that $\textbf{E}\{\textbf{E}(X\mid X+Y)\} = \textbf{E}(X)$

**MY ATTEMPT**

Firsly, I would like to determine the distribution of $Z = X+Y$. Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent,
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(Z = z) = \textbf{P}(X + Y = z) = \sum_{x=0}^{z}\textbf{P}(X = x,Y = z - x) = \sum_{x=0}^{z}\textbf{P}(X = x)\textbf{P}(Y = z-x)
\end{align*}

Consequently, we have

\begin{align*}
p_{Z}(z) & = \textbf{P}(Z = z) = \sum_{x=0}^{z}{n\choose z-x}p^{z-x}(1-p)^{n-z+x}{m\choose x}p^{x}(1-p)^{m-x}\\
& = \sum_{x=0}^{z}{n\choose z-x}{m\choose x}p^{z}(1-p)^{m + n - z} = {m+n\choose z}p^{z}(1-p)^{m+n-z}
\end{align*}

Another possible approach is to consider each Binomial distribution as a sum of Bernoulli distributions. Therefore $Z\sim\text{Binomial}(m+n,p)$. Based on this, could someone help me out?

**EDIT**

(a) As a consequence from the independence between $X$ and $Y$, we have
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(X = x | X + Y = s) & = \frac{\textbf{P}(X = x, X+Y = s)}{\textbf{P}(X+Y = s)} = \frac{\textbf{P}(X = x)\textbf{P}(Y = s - x)}{\textbf{P}(X+Y = s)}\\\\
& = \frac{\displaystyle{m\choose x}{n\choose s-x}p^{s}(1-p)^{m+n-s}}{\displaystyle{m+n\choose s}p^{s}(1-p)^{m+n-s}} = \frac{\displaystyle{m\choose x}{n\choose s - x}}{\displaystyle{m+n\choose s}}
\end{align*}

(b) According to wikipedia ([Hypergeometric random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Definition)), we have

\begin{align*}
\textbf{E}(X | X + Y) = \frac{sm}{m+n}\quad\text{and}\quad\textbf{V}(X | X+Y) = \ldots
\end{align*}

(c) Finally, we have

\begin{align*}
\textbf{E}\{\textbf{E}(X|X+Y)\} = \frac{m}{m+n}\textbf{E}(X+Y) = \frac{m(m+n)p}{m+n} = mp = \textbf{E}(X)
\end{align*}

Comment: You definitely can consider each binomial as the sum of bernoulli's. If you choose to go the way of densities, what will really help is to consider Vandermonde’s identity (first discovered by Zhu Shijie in 1303 in Ancient China): 

$$
\sum_{j=0}^k{n\choose k-j} {m\choose j}= {m+n \choose k}
$$

Comment: I would also check the summation indices you have above.

Comment: There are some conceptual mistakes in your attempt and edit. The second equality in the "My Attempt" is wrong (what you get next would be correct, using Vandermonde's identity, but that's not a consequence of what you wrote just before). The same is true also for the first equality in "My Edit" (here, use first the definition of conditional probability).

Comment: Thanks for the contributions, user52227. I think I have implemented them correctly this time. By the way, could you provide an answer to the last updated question?

Comment: Where's the last updated question?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it. Anyway, I was asking if someone could provide the expectation of the hypergeometric distribution.